# uwsgi , application not found

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi

Ok so I have been trying to find a solution to this for 2 days now but I cannot seem to make much progress. I am running this on a nginx server but that appears to be fine.

I copied over a python application environment from an older server (python 2.7.4) to a new server (which is a lower version?! python 2.7.3)

within my error logs for the uwsgi I am getting an error:

> --- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
>
> [pid: 1713|app: -1|req: -1/9] [IP_ADDR] () {44 vars in 866 bytes} [Tue
>   Feb 23 11:37:48 2016] GET / => generated 21 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1
>   500) 2 headers in 83 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
>
> --- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
>
> [pid: 1711|app: -1|req: -1/10] [IP_ADDR] () {46 vars in 843 bytes}
>   [Tue Feb 23 11:37:48 2016] GET /favicon.ico => generated 21 bytes in 0
>   msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 83 bytes (1 switches on core 0)

I honestly do not have any clue what so ever to do. I removed plugins=python from the ini file, and this fixed a 502 error I was getting. then to fix the application not found people have been saying to add in plugins=python (which obviously I cannot because it breaks it).

so now I am stuck in an infinite loop. it says check my start up logs but this is the only log which appears to be changed on trying to run the web application from client side.

I am running this to start the uwsgi:

```
uwsgi --binary-path /srv/1/env/bin/uwsgi --ini /srv/1/2/production.ini
```

Comment: You do need `python-dev` to use `plugins=python`, check that you have that installed.

Comment: I actually fixed it... it was a long and painful mission of going through every single dependency and trying to make sure they existed... which is funny when half of them are custom / out of business...

Comment: Dependencies of what?

This is ridiculously difficult to debug. Why can't this error just be more specific?